# What is the TypeScript equivalent of Java's `?` unknown wildcard?

Tags: generics, typescript

Say I want to declare an array of generics in Typescript. What would be the equivalent of the unknown wildcard '?' in Java?

This does compile, but seems a little awkward `MyGeneric<any>[];`

I would like a declaration equivalent to Java `MyGeneric<?>[];`, that is, a single type array, but the type is not known when it is declared.

Comment: Actually "any" IS the generic type in typescript. I don't understand the question...

Comment: Pick your favorite symbol and rename it, lol ;P `type ƒ = any; MyGeneric<ƒ>[];`

Comment: `any` is not a generic type, it's disabling type safety entirely and should be avoided. The difference is more obvious if you consider a bound wildcard: `? extends SomeType`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think Typescript has late binding generic types.

But if this particular code was in the context of a function you could use generics to achieve a similar thing.

```
function example<T>(val:T){
  let a : T[]

  return [val]
}

let a = example(4)
// number[] :: [4]

let b = example('hello')
// string[] :: ['hello']
```

Here is an interactive example: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20example%3CT%3E(val%3AT)%7B%0D%0A%20%20let%20a%20%3A%20T%5B%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20%5Bval%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20example(4)%0D%0A%2F%2F%20number%5B%5D%20%3A%3A%20%5B4%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20example('hello')%0D%0A%2F%2F%20string%5B%5D%20%3A%3A%20%5B'hello'%5D)

Try hovering over `a` or `b` to see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

> Say I want to declare an array of generics in Typescript. What would be the equivalent of the unknown wildcard '?' in Java?

To have a string array

```
var foo:string[];
```

This is same as the following as far as TypeScript is concerned:

```
var foo:Array<string>;
```

If you want an array of *anything* then just use `any`:

```
var foo:any[] = ['asdf',123]; // Anything is allowed in this array.
```

Comment: I think a `?` wildcard indicates a single type, but the type is not yet known.
Which is different to saying the array could contain anything.

Comment: @JamesForbes, this is exactly the distinction I was trying to make. Thank you.

Comment: I think here the question is what is equivalent to a wildcard, not specifically to any type array. sometimes we need to use late generic like ` function fun(param: Type<? extends Base>) {}` so what can be the solution in this case ? plus if we are comming from java side then what abour `? supers Base` ?

Comment: @9me Since you are using a function, you may do `function fun<T extends Base>(param: Type<T>){}`.
Regarding the `super`, there is a `Partial<T>` type which mimics it. To do the equivalent of `T super U`, you can do `T extends Partial<U>`.