# TypeScript generics equivalent of Java's "? extends MyClass"

Tags: java, typescript, generics, covariance

What would be the TypeScript equivalent of Java's `? extends MyClass`?

I can emulate it thusly:

```
function myFunc <TComponent extends MyBaseClass>(param: ComponentFixture<TComponent>) {}
```

but is there a way to shorten it to something like:

```
function myFunc(param: ComponentFixture<? extends MyBaseClass>) {} // causes error TS1138: Parameter declaration expected
```

?

Perhaps this is not implemented yet?

Or there is another syntax for it?

Or there is a reason why this is not supported?

Comment: Please see [Typescript equivalent of ? unknown wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239227/typescript-equivalent-of-unknown-wildcard)

Comment: Thanks. Related, but mine is more specific (with the "extends"), which could theoretically lead to different answers.

Comment: what would be the difference? To me those look like they would provide the same typing. And if you want to achieve java's `ComponentFixture<?>` you can just have `ComponentFixture<any>` it would be the same typing (more or less), maybe `ComponentFixture<Object>` would be closer to what java has.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no such syntax in TypeScript.
Feel free to suggest it to the TypeScript team.

But I would guess even if they agree, it will be a very low priority.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value for a generic type to be a `MyBaseClass` within a `ComponentFixture`:

```js
type ComponentFixture<TComponent extends MyBaseClass=MyBaseClass> = {...}

function myFunc (param: ComponentFixture) {}
```

This way if you don't provide any generic arguments within `<>` typescript will fallback to the default type of `MyBaseClass`.