# Wildcard in typescript

Tags: typescript, wildcard, angular2-forms

As I am pretty new to typescript, I would like to expand on a question that was posted some time ago, about wildcards in typescript. [Here is the original question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239227/typescript-equivalent-of-unknown-wildcard)

My Angular 2/ Web.API/MVC application is using a recursive search in my database to bring back a distinct list of types that populate a filter modal, in 3 different columns. When the user selects one value on one of the select lists,
i would like to populate the other 2 select lists with all the available values that match the first select list. But currently, 'UNDEFINED' is getting passed from the component into the controller, causing it to look for empty values, instead of all values.

so here is the obligatory code from my component:

My Update Event:

```
    UpdateAllLookups(event) {
    this.allLookups = [];
    if ("year" == event.srcElement.id) {

        this.corrCodesfilter.rgln_Year = this.getSelectedItem("year").value
    } else { this.corrCodesfilter.rgln_Year = this.corrCodesfilter.rgln_Year; }
    if ("regType" == event.srcElement.id) {

            this.corrCodesfilter.rgln_type_code = this.getSelectedItem("regType").value;
    } else { this.corrCodesfilter.rgln_type_code = this.corrCodesfilter.rgln_type_code;}

    if("valdtnCode"== event.srcElement.id){
        this.corrCodesfilter.valdtn_code = this.getSelectedItem("valdtnCode").value;
    } else { this.corrCodesfilter.valdtn_code = this.corrCodesfilter.valdtn_code;}
    this._corrCodeService.getLookupsUpdate(Global.BASE_CORRECTION_CODE_ENDPOINT + "GetLookupsUpdate?", this.corrCodesfilter)
        .subscribe(allLookups => {
            this.allLookups = allLookups;
            this.getYearLookups();
            this.getRegLookups();
            this.indLoading = false;
        }, error => this.msg = <any>error);
}
```

If I was working in c#, I would pass:

```
   if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.corrCodesFilter.rgln_Year)){
   this.corrCodesFilter.rgln_Year = *;}
```

Is there anything I can do to have a wildcard passed in if a value is undefined? I havent been able  to hit my controller with undefined values, or I would have done it there. Any help given is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you right, but an equivalent of that C# expression would be: this.corrCodesFilter.rgln_Year = this.corrCodesFilter.rgln_Year || '*'

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following to assign a default value if the field is undefined:

```
 this.corrCodesFilter.rgln_Year = this.corrCodesFilter.rgln_Year || '*';
```

The expression above will return either `this.corrCodesFilter.rgln_Year` if it is not `undefined` or `'*'` if `this.corrCodesFilter.rgln_Year` is `undefined`.

Comment: this works for the rgln_Year, but because the value of rgln_type_code and valdtn_code are both numbers, it will not compile with '*' as the value. any workarounds there?

Comment: Well, since you want the value to be a number or a string you could change the type to be `'*'|number` instead, Ex: `let ddd : '*' | number  = 10;
    ddd = ddd || '*';` But it depends what you do with those fields