# How to declare a collection with elements that extend some type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a `Set`, and such code, that uses the `Set`:

```
class A {

    public test1(): void {
        console.log("1");
    }
}

class B extends A {

    public test2(): void {
        console.log("2");
    }
}

class C extends B {

    public test3(): void {
        console.log("3");
    }
}

let mySet: Set<any extends B> = new HashSet();//LINE X
```

At LINE X I get error in generics. What is a correct way to declare the such Set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to declare `let mySet: Set<B>`. Any type compatible with `B` will be valid, meaning any instance of `B` but also any derived classes (such as `C`).

```
class A {

    public test1(): void {
        console.log("1");
    }
}

class B extends A {

    public test2(): void {
        console.log("2");
    }
}

class C extends B {

    public test3(): void {
        console.log("3");
    }
}

let mySet: Set<B> = new Set<B>();//LINE X
mySet.add(new B());
mySet.add(new C());
mySet.add(new A()); // error
```

When you retrieve instances from the set you will not know the actual type, you will need to test the type.

Comment: As Titan described, because `C` is extension of `B`, `C` instances may be used in every place that `B` is expected. It's like relation Pearson -> Teacher: each Teacher is a Person, but not each Person is a Teacher ;)

Comment: There is no equivalent of wildcard generics in TypeScript, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239227/typescript-equivalent-of-unknown-wildcard

Comment: @Pavel_K, the example in the original question does not show any need for wildcards.  This answer is sufficient unless you can refine the question.